# Using "pull request" to request a merge on a branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

If I understood it properly, git [pull request](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull) command is used in the following scenario:

- I find a open source project which I consider interesting. I want to develop some extra features on the top of this project, however I have no write permissions on that repository (let's call it Xrepo).
- So, for ex if I'm on GitHub, I can create a fork and then work on my own repo which will contain a copy of the original code and use the original repo (Xrepo) as the "upstream".
- Now, if I consider that I've developed something useful to be shared and integrated on Xrepo, I can send a "pull request" containing my changes to Xrepo.
- If the Xrepo's administrator agrees, he will approve the request and my changes are merged into Xrepo.

In the above scenario we are using pull request as a way to commit code in a repository which we don't have write permissions.

My question is if we can also use pull request to have the same behavior with read-only branches within the same repo. 
For example, imagine I have a GIT repository where I have write permissions on branch X but only read-permissions on branch Y. Can I commit my changes to branch X and send a pull request to get this changes merged into branch Y?
If yes, what parameters should I use? (remember I'm working always on the same repo).

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you're able to do the pull request workflow between branches.

Below is an example.

[image]
Right from Github's website, I'm able to create a new file and either commit it to the branch I'm on or create a new branch and 'automatically' create a pull request.

---

[image]
Above you can see the 'create a new pull request' page where I select the original branch that I branched from and my current branch.

---

[image]
Now you can see the full pull request.