Working with GitHub repository with no local git project
I want to merge a branch into main in a remote repository hosted on GitHub.
I don't want to clone the repository locally first.
How can I do this please?

You can do a pull request between branches in the same repository: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38000477/7976758

Your question is not clear.
In git the merge is done locally on you local git repository, you cant avoid having the desired branch locally, but you dont need to clone it as well.
In your local repository add second remote for the Github repository
git remote add github <url>

Now you need to fetch the desired branch
git fetch github <github branch>

Now you code is locally and you can do the merge
git merge main <github branch>


Demo Code
#!/bin/bash
set -x

# Clone the original repo
cd      /tmp
rm -rf  UnixLabs
git     clone git@github.com:nirgeier/UnixLabs.git 

# move into the directory
cd  /tmp/UnixLabs

echo -e ""
# Add second remote to the repository
git remote add origin2 git@github.com:nirgeier/BashEscapeRoom.git

# Now we have 2 remotes
# Fetch the second remote branch
echo -e ""
git fetch origin2 main

# now you can merge them 2
echo -e ""
git merge origin2/main

Output
+ cd /tmp
+ rm -rf UnixLabs
+ git clone git@github.com:nirgeier/UnixLabs.git
Cloning into 'UnixLabs'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 89, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Total 89 (delta 0), reused 23 (delta 0), pack-reused 65
Receiving objects: 100% (89/89), 6.13 MiB | 4.69 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7/7), done.
+ cd /tmp/UnixLabs
+ echo -e ''

+ git remote add origin2 git@github.com:nirgeier/BashEscapeRoom.git
+ echo -e ''

+ git fetch origin2 main
remote: Enumerating objects: 78, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (78/78), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (70/70), done.
remote: Total 78 (delta 5), reused 78 (delta 5), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (78/78), 6.10 MiB | 4.39 MiB/s, done.
From github.com:nirgeier/BashEscapeRoom
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      main       -> origin2/main
+ echo -e ''

+ git merge origin2/main
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories


I think the question is: how to merge a branch into main using GitHub web interface, without cloning the repo locally.
